# Second monitor without signal on Debian

Tags: debian, nvidia, display, xrandr

Recently, I had a problem with my Linux Mint installation and decided to install Debian 11 Stable with the nonfree drivers, and everything is working well so far, except for my second monitor, which is working normally during boot, but when the display manager is start, it goes black, here's my devices:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

xrandr says there's two providers:

```
xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x43 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink         Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0xd4 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink     Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

Initially I though there was some kind of problem with the drivers, and I replaced the Noveau drivers for Nvidia proprietary ones, which didn't solved the problem, but I got some results:

By running nvidia-settings, I was able to see the nvidia settings panel where I could see the second monitor detected there (although it didn't received any signal).

By including a nvidia.conf inside /etc/X11/xorg.cong.d/, I was able to make the second monitor work, but the laptop screen stopped working, so I had to remove the file to revert.

How can I get my second monitor working alongside my laptop monitor?

Obs.: I already noticed that there's similar threads here and at the debian user forums, but none of them had any kind of solution I could replicate...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I've received an answer on the Debian User Forums that actually worked for me, and although it may not solve the problem for everyone who is experiencing it, here it goes:

-I replaced the Nouveau drivers with the proprietary NVIDIA drivers that were available at the apt repository that Debian provided

-I installed the nvidia-xconfig utility and used it with the --prime flag

I put this on my .xsessionrc:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
xrandr --dpi 96
```

If you're interested in following how that was solved, please check it [here](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=154216). Thanks CynicalDebian!